# How do I implement the Facebook SDK for .NET into a Windows Mobile 6.5 application?

Tags: c#, facebook, .net-3.5

Basically what I want to do is use the SDK available [here](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/), to post specific status-updates to a profile which has been logged into.

Now it seems to me that the project has been on a standstill for some days and the documentation is REALLY lacking.

My current setup is as stated below:

- Visual Studio 2008
- Windows Mobile 6 Classic Emulator
- .Net 3.5 (Compact I believe)

So far I've been able to get the emulator running and get some GPS stats from a fake GSP generator.
What I've not been able to do however is figuring out the Facebook SDK. It seems that most of the examples (or atleast the ones I actually need, such as Authentication) are based on .Net 4.0 and I can't find any .Net 3.5 examples on authentication or how to log-in using the SDK.
There are examples that point out how to post updates etc. for 3.5 but there aren't any for authentication/login etc.

So does anyone know how to use the SDK with the setup I described above? When I figure it all out I'll make a blog post on my blig explaining all the steps I took to get it all working together and will post a link here for others.
But until I know how to get the SDK working for 3.5 I can do nothing.

So please help me find the answer. I'll try looking through the source some more. However since I don't have VS2010 I can't look at the .sln files they used for the source... So will try, but can't promise anything

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK isn't supported on WinMo 6.5 with the compact framework. However, interacting with facebook is really easy, provided the framework provide you with some required capabilities:

1) You must be able to leverage a WebBrowser control to manage user authentification, as demonstrated [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) .

2) You then will be able to interact with Facebook through simple POST and GET request. Demonstrated [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) for a Wall post request.